# dygraph - how to change the default time period range selector is set too

Tags: css, range, dygraphs

the example code for the dygraph range selector , has as default the range selector representing the whole time period.

Are there examples of dygraph anywhere that have the range selector set to initially respresent only 2 days, or a week, etc? If not, how could one go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 4):

You can set the `dateWindow` property, for example:

```
new Dygraph(div, data, {
  ...
  dateWindow: [3, 7]
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eM2Mg/2989/)